# read a file and converts each decimal into a binary number

Tags: python

Reads the text file (the file name is given as a parameter) and converts each decimal number into a binary number. All decimal numbers are positive, so you do not need to account for the negative scenario. Print each converted binary number to the console, one per line.
(Create a module named binary that has each of the functions listed below. You will notice these functions are used in the main.py file, which is how you will test your code).

File `dec2bin.txt`

```
11
2090
103
58 
9049
20012948
129129
291
2039193
1234872589
8717950
```

[image]

```
main.py

import binary as b    

b.dec2bin("dec2bin.txt")    

print()
```

what am I doing wrong?
my code is not working and I tried different coding.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Please don't screenshot your code. Copy and paste it into your question. Highlight what you pasted, and click the `{}` button in the editor to preserve line-feeds and white-space. I made an attempt at doing this what you pasted (note that lines that are preceded with 4 spaces are shown as code).

Comment: It didn't let me copy and paste the code. I tried that for some reason I kept getting an error message.

Comment: As for your code, you'll want to loop through each line in your file. `for line in file:` and inside this loop you will do your `dec2bin` and `print()`. My guess is that assignment is for you to learn 1) How to read a file into python 2) How to loop through its contents, so you are half way there with your current code.

Comment: I know how to use the rt, wt, and so on I never done revers. I know how to use the main.py to code but I guess I'm confused on how to create the correct codes in a file without changing the main.py I'm new to python.

Comment: I figured it out thank you for the tips

Answer (score 1):

```py
def dec2bin(file): 

    with open(file, 'r') as f: 
 
        for line in f:

            print(bin(int(line)).replace("0b", ""))
```

```py
def bin2dec(file):

    with open(file, 'r') as f:

        for line in f:

            print(int(line, 2))
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
# Inside binary.py file
def dec2bin(data):
    lst = []
    for a in data:
        lst.append(bin(int(a))[2:])
    return(lst)

# another file.

from binary import *
with open('test.txt') as f:
    data = f.read().splitlines()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(dec2bin(data))
```

OUTPUT

```py
['1011', '100000101010', '1100111', '111010', '10001101011001', '1001100010101111110010100', '11111100001101001', '100100011', '111110001110110011001', '1001001100110101010100100001101', '100001010000011001111110']
```